# Php 7.3.13 Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

Since my host has updated php from version 7.0.3 to version 7.3.13 of php, I am getting the following error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

It worked perfectly before the version change, if I use var_export on the function, with version 7.0.3 I get:

```
array (
    0 => 'block_menu.html',
    1 => 'block_fiches_pratiques.html',
    2 => 'block_fiche_aleatoire.html',
    3 => 'block_random_annonces.html',
    4 => 'block_consult.html',
    5 => 'block_random_oquerhtml',
    6 => 'block_user_information.html',
    7 => 'block_horoscope.html',
    8 => 'block_favoris.html',
    9 => 'block_links.html',)
```

If I use var_export on the function, with version 7.3.13, it shows me 10 times the first letter of the character string, `not array (bbbbbbbbbbb)`

Here is the offending code:

```
if($left_block_ary !='') {
    foreach ($left_block_ary as $block => $value){
    $template->assign_block_vars('left_block_files', array(
    'LEFT_BLOCKS'       => portal_block_template($value),
    'LEFT_BLOCK_ID'     => $left_block_id[$block],
    'LEFT_BLOCK_SOURCE' => htmlspecialchars_decode(smilies_pass(censor_text($left_block_source[$block]))),
    'LEFT_BLOCK_NOM'    => $left_block_nom[$block],                     
    ));
    } } else {}
```

Thank you for your help...

Answer (score 1):

Your `if($left_block_ary !='')` is what is not checking or isn't working correctly. `$left_block_ary` is an array and therefore it will never be equal to `''` thus that check always passes even in cases where the array is empty instead you can use the

```
if(!empty($left_block_ary)) {
   //perform your loop here
}
```

check to check whether the array is empty or not.

Comment: `isEmpty` replace with `empty`

Comment: Better check if the value `is_iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message caused by `$left_block_ary` is not an array. If the variable `$left_block_ary` can not only be an array then you should put validation using `is_array()` to check if variable is an array before using  `foreach()` and you may also use `empty()` to determine if has value like this example:

```
if (is_array($left_block_ary)) {

    foreach ($left_block_ary as $block => $value){
        echo $value."<br>";
    }

    if (empty($left_block_ary)) {
       echo 'array is empty'
    }
} else {
    echo 'not array';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

But precisely the problem is there, with the php version before 7.3.13, with the test of the `var_export function ($ left_block_ary);` , it shows me the table well.
Since version 7.3.13, it displays 10 times the first letter of the character chain, not array (bbbbbbbbbbb).

See my first post.

I changed `if ($ left_block_ary! = '')` To `if (! Empty ($ left_block_ary))`, it makes the code cleaner, but of course it doesn't change the error.